# geom_smooth does not plot SE with separate data frame for local adjustment smoothing

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot a "fitted" mixed models regression by plotting predicted/fitted values and a regression line for each condition with SE's included. Unfortunately, the SE is not plotted (although I do think that the grey shading of the legend indicates that it is processed).

`newdat` contains the data to plot the predicted values (geom_point); `nd` contains the data needed to plot the lines via geom_smooth().

```
newdat <- structure(list(v0 = c(55L, 90L, 30L, 23L, 74L, 48L, 25L, 25L, 
60L, 69L, 55L, 41L, 34L, 41L, 53L, 76L, 72L, 64L, 34L, 37L, 75L, 
21L, 26L, 14L, 24L, 19L), treatment = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("hc", "nhc"), class = "factor"), 
    cse = c(2, 2, 6, 6, -4, -4, 5, 5, -4, -4, -3, -3, -2, -2, 
    3, 3, 2, 2, -4, -4, -7, -7, 4, 4, 2, 2), dv280 = structure(c(28.5954553607209, 
    29.0010807407473, 0.820231380215773, 3.35865456461513, 49.8359456217717, 
    24.461804847022, 6.23032836368822, 0.772936154511909, 41.8150506885472, 
    31.9089377911506, 25.2183508293096, 29.203718756273, 23.4674396239055, 
    18.5277638674685, 14.154110078194, 38.9009660948022, 22.6178239314942, 
    33.7517449606509, 26.9191029554161, 20.5609256858118, 55.5863616856965, 
    20.0644146304084, 2.85339319855906, 1.65402829619576, 10.8349022942953, 
    3.82267888202684), .Dim = c(26L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(c("1", 
    "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "11", "12", "13", "14", 
    "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", 
    "25", "26", "27", "28"), NULL)), plo = c(18.2940632968672, 
    8.70682874092615, -9.57004073754051, -7.05295432875793, 35.2691733515267, 
    14.2687966060566, -3.12208622604343, -8.52627071371677, 30.1788256344375, 
    18.2506947724591, 14.8705702665525, 20.3644901882128, 15.3980231727933, 
    10.4235410902273, 3.52894178176158, 22.3750340692014, 7.67201979003711, 
    21.2004011925819, 16.8945364920955, 10.6654316626679, 39.1117560188314, 
    4.71896161593837, -5.54649636719771, -8.03839072475669, 3.25706574634023, 
    -4.38303434571468), phi = c(38.8968474245745, 49.2953327405684, 
    11.2105034979721, 13.7702634579882, 64.4027178920167, 34.6548130879875, 
    15.5827429534199, 10.0721430227406, 53.4512757426569, 45.5671808098421, 
    35.5661313920666, 38.0429473243332, 31.5368560750176, 26.6319866447097, 
    24.7792783746264, 55.4268981204031, 37.5636280729513, 46.3030887287198, 
    36.9436694187367, 30.4564197089558, 72.0609673525617, 35.4098676448784, 
    11.2532827643158, 11.3464473171482, 18.4127388422504, 12.0283921097684
    ), tlo = c(18.2877068225676, 8.70360144639113, -9.57634287064189, 
    -7.05924355454202, 35.2646774598802, 14.2623725847359, -3.12908722334489, 
    -8.53331173874155, 30.1731979587424, 18.2458999214011, 14.8642422705033, 
    20.3570830595245, 15.3899100922942, 10.4154628193239, 3.52277889155111, 
    22.371071031997, 7.6676378822382, 21.1951836536363, 16.8880045983016, 
    10.6588146263129, 39.1077806378248, 4.71469379607788, -5.55429056032973, 
    -8.04514630529966, 3.24842694535383, -4.39101280006747), 
    thi = c(38.9032038988741, 49.2985600351034, 11.2168056310734, 
    13.7765526837723, 64.4072137836632, 34.6612371093081, 15.5897439507213, 
    10.0791840477654, 53.456903418352, 45.5719756609001, 35.5724593881158, 
    38.0503544530215, 31.5449691555168, 26.6400649156131, 24.7854412648369, 
    55.4308611576074, 37.5680099807502, 46.3083062676655, 36.9502013125306, 
    30.4630367453107, 72.0649427335683, 35.4141354647389, 11.2610769574479, 
    11.3532028976912, 18.4213776432368, 12.0363705641212)), .Names = c("v0", 
"treatment", "cse", "dv280", "plo", "phi", "tlo", "thi"), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L), class =

 "data.frame")
    nd <- structure(list(v0 = c(55L, 90L, 30L, 23L, 74L, 48L, 25L, 25L, 
60L, 69L, 55L, 41L, 34L, 41L, 53L, 76L, 72L, 64L, 34L, 37L, 75L, 
21L, 26L, 14L, 24L, 19L), treatment = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("hc", "nhc"), class = "factor"), 
    cse = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), dv280 = structure(c(32.0471186922315, 
    32.4527440722579, 11.1752213747477, 13.713644559147, 42.9326189587504, 
    17.5584781840008, 14.8594866924648, 9.4020944832885, 34.911724025526, 
    25.0056111281293, 20.0408558320436, 24.0262237590071, 20.0157762923948, 
    15.0761005359579, 19.3316050754599, 44.0784610920682, 26.0694872630048, 
    37.2034082921615, 20.0157762923948, 13.6575990227905, 43.5055400254093, 
    7.98359297012116, 9.75671986158034, 8.55735495921703, 14.2865656258059, 
    7.27434221353748), .Dim = c(26L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(c("1", 
    "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "11", "12", "13", "14", 
    "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", 
    "25", "26", "27", "28"), NULL)), plo = c(22.5072031474275, 
    13.0500664185171, 4.05863186267882, 5.77259649335957, 28.5121051842211, 
    9.29736790581986, 7.2048329083037, 1.78971324244184, 24.2096188947274, 
    11.7540646048434, 10.363946079095, 16.7677263682142, 13.0339097497873, 
    7.77962797988299, 10.0943827426394, 29.0914605330986, 11.9778881852231, 
    25.4951576099086, 13.0339097497873, 6.63425372645495, 28.8025761975293, 
    -0.238742065354621, 2.26914358668319, -1.1076157441286, 6.49404176281806, 
    -1.31100367364568), phi = c(41.5870342370355, 51.8554217259987, 
    18.2918108868166, 21.6546926249345, 57.3531327332797, 25.8195884621816, 
    22.5141404766259, 17.0144757241352, 45.6138291563245, 38.2571576514153, 
    29.7177655849923, 31.2847211497999, 26.9976428350024, 22.3725730920328, 
    28.5688274082805, 59.0654616510377, 40.1610863407866, 48.9116589744144, 
    26.9976428350024, 20.6809443191261, 58.2085038532893, 16.2059280055969, 
    17.2442961364775, 18.2223256625627, 22.0790894887938, 15.8596881007206
    ), tlo = c(22.500339650347, 13.046690851483, 4.0494338564546, 
    5.76435239847513, 28.5075637077657, 9.28944290164532, 7.19628070358881, 
    1.78111359966419, 24.2035002837825, 11.7491226514857, 10.3571796788833, 
    16.7587079630338, 13.024534493447, 7.77065645403329, 10.0872945063297, 
    29.087090666816, 11.9732407398515, 25.4895645373964, 13.024534493447, 
    6.62493376528452, 28.7981219380453, -0.246704406534527, 2.26040076852036, 
    -1.1143904969611, 6.4856407045028, -1.3186296516059), thi = c(41.593897734116, 
    51.8587972930328, 18.3010088930408, 21.6629367198189, 57.3576742097352, 
    25.8275134663562, 22.5226926813408, 17.0230753669128, 45.6199477672694, 
    38.2620996047729, 29.7245319852039, 31.2937395549803, 27.0070180913427, 
    22.3815446178825, 28.5759156445901, 59.0698315173204, 40.1657337861582, 
    48.9172520469266, 27.0070180913427, 20.6902642802966, 58.2129581127733, 
    16.2138903467768, 17.2530389546403, 18.2291004153952, 22.0874905471091, 
    15.8673140786809)), .Names = c("v0", "treatment", "cse", 
"dv280", "plo", "phi", "tlo", "thi"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L), class = "data.frame")
p <- ggplot(data=newdat, mapping=aes(x=v0, y=dv280, colour=treatment)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(data=nd, method='lm', se=TRUE) +
  scale_colour_discrete(guide=guide_legend(title.position='left', title.hjust=1))
p + .mytheme + coord_cartesian(xlim=c(-20,100)) +     
  geom_hline(yintercept=0, colour='gray35', linetype='dashed') +
  geom_vline(xintercept=0, colour='gray35', linetype='dashed')
```

This is all nice and dandy but unfortunately, the SE is not displayed:

[image]

I don't get why the SE is dropped (or perhaps overwritten by/with something else, given that the legend appears to indicate that the SE parameter is seen and recognized).

The code to generate `newdat` and `nd` is as follows with the main difference that for `nd` the value for `cse` is set to zero.

```
m <- lmer(dv280 ~ 1 + v0:treatment + cse + (0 + v0 | pp), data=dat, REML=TRUE)
newdat <- data.frame(
  v0=dat$v0,
  treatment=dat$treatment, 
  cse=dat$cse,
  dv280=0)
newdat <- newdat[-c(9,10),]
mm <- model.matrix(terms(m), newdat)
newdat$dv280 <- mm %*% fixef(m)
pvar1 <- diag(mm %*% tcrossprod(vcov(m), mm))
tvar1 <- pvar1 + VarCorr(m)$pp[1]
newdat <- data.frame(newdat, plo=newdat$dv280 - 2 * sqrt(pvar1), phi=newdat$dv280 + 2 * sqrt(pvar1), 
         tlo=newdat$dv280 - 2 * sqrt(tvar1), thi=newdat$dv280 + 2 * sqrt(tvar1)) 
nd <- data.frame(
  v0=dat$v0,
  treatment=dat$treatment, 
  cse=0,
  dv280=0)
nd <- nd[-c(9,10),]
mm <- model.matrix(terms(m), nd)
nd$dv280 <- mm %*% fixef(m)
pvar1 <- diag(mm %*% tcrossprod(vcov(m), mm))
tvar1 <- pvar1 + VarCorr(m)$pp[1]
nd <- data.frame(nd, plo=nd$dv280 - 2 * sqrt(pvar1), phi=nd$dv280 + 2 * sqrt(pvar1), 
         tlo=nd$dv280 - 2 * sqrt(tvar1), thi=nd$dv280 + 2 * sqrt(tvar1))
```

Comment: not sure, but try `geom_smooth(data=newdat, method='lm', se=TRUE)` you had `geom_smooth(data=nd, method='lm', se=TRUE)`

Comment: That is intended given that I want to use a slightly different model prediction to plot the regression line.

Comment: ... once more not sure, because it is hard for me to understand what is going on, when the estimation of the model is not there:
`geom_smooth(aes(ymin = plo, ymax = phi), data=nd[nd$treatment=="hc", ], method='lm', se = TRUE, stat="identity")` ... same for the second and you must adjust the subset with the corresponding aes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code,

```
p <- ggplot(data=newdat, mapping=aes(x=v0, y=dv280, colour=treatment)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(data=nd, method='lm', se=TRUE) +
  scale_colour_discrete(guide=guide_legend(title.position='left', title.hjust=1))
```

You use `newdat` as the dataset in `geom_points(...)`, and `nd` in `geom_smooth(...)`. The problem is that `nd` apparently contains the fitted values (e.g. the predictions). So the se around the "data" from `nd` is 0. You can see the by typing:

```
p <- ggplot(data=nd, mapping=aes(x=v0, y=dv280, colour=treatment)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(data=nd, method='lm', se=TRUE) +
  scale_colour_discrete(guide=guide_legend(title.position='left', title.hjust=1))
```

[image]

The points in `nd` lie perfectly on a line, so `se=0`. If the point of using `nd` is to calculate the `lm` using some subset of your data, then provide that as the dataset to `geom_smooth(...)`. For example, the code below plots all the points, but `lm` is done on the subset where `dv280 > 5`:

```
p <- ggplot(data=newdat, mapping=aes(x=v0, y=dv280, colour=treatment)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(data=subset(newdat,dv280>5), method='lm', se=TRUE) +
  scale_colour_discrete(guide=guide_legend(title.position='left', title.hjust=1))
```

**Edit:** In response to OP's comment.

It looks like you are fitting an `lme model` to `dat$dv280`. So the *data* is in `dat`. On the other hand, `newdat$dv280` is the *prediction* based on the model parameters and a model matrix containing `v0`, `treatment`, and `cse`. In addition, `nd$dv280` is the *prediction* based on `v0` and `treatment`, with `cse=0`. So it is not surprising that a plot of `nd$dv280` vs. `v0`, grouped by `treatment`, will be perfectly linear. Nowhere in your `ggplot` code are you plotting the actual data (e.g., `dat$dv280`). The apparent scatter is solely due to the effect of `cse`. So at this point I'm not really sure what you are trying to demonstrate with this plot (??).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. That helped tremendously. I am looking for [a figure like this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2049298/idealplot.png). This issue with the linked example is that the regression lines are off with respect to the intercept that the mixed models regression estimated (specifically 0.54) because the lines are based on a fit by geom_smooth() of the predicted points instead of being the fitted line from the estimated model.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. The figure in your link is identical, as far as I can tell, to what you would get by using `data=newdat` instead of `data=nd` in `geom_smooth(...)` in your original code. What would help me the most is showing the code you used to create `nd` from `newdat`. Could you add that you your original question as an edit?

Comment: I should clarify ... it was already late yesterday evening. Both newdat and nd contain predictions. The difference is that in nd one of the predictors has been set to population average (here zero) to make sure that the regression lines are visualized properly on top of the predicted points from newdat. Then I also want to add SE shading based on newdat. So the figure I am looking for is a variant of the one I [linked](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2049298/idealplot.png) to but with regression lines based on nd instead of newdat.

Comment: Added code to create `newdat` and `nd` per request of @jlhoward.

Comment: Following up on @jlhoward edit. The longer story is: an initial model did not have a significant difference between the treatment levels. This was evident visually from the scatterplot of the raw data with SE's around the fitted lines. The SE of one level incorporated the regression line of the other level. With `cse` added, however, the difference became significant (is explainable). So I want to plot the above non-sig scatterplot next to a similar figure to show how `cse` works to make the difference significant: by making the difference in slopes larger and SE's smaller.

Comment: I thought the above approach was appropriate: plot the scatter due to `cse` with regression lines without `cse` to make sure that they reflect the estimated regression equation that has an intercept at 0.54. Evidently this intercept is different when `geom_smooth()` calculates a simple regression for each treatment's data points (whether from a prediction or the raw interval). So I tried to calculate two different sets of predictions and use the appropriate elements for each element of the figure.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, I think the following code might put you on the right track. You can explicitly state the standard errors:

```
model <- lm(dv280 ~ v0, data=newdat)

err <- stats::predict(model, newdata=newdat, se=TRUE)
newdat$ucl <- err$fit + 1.96 * err$se.fit
newdat$lcl <- err$fit - 1.96 * err$se.fit

qplot(v0, dv280, data=newdat, colour=treatment) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(ymin=lcl, ymax=ucl), data=newdat, method="lm")
```

This will give you the following figure:

[image]